# Authorization header with HttpGet with proxy

Tags: http, oauth, http-get, http-proxy, bearer-token

I am using HttpGet with a proxy setting. The call works for endpoints that don't need an authorization token. For services that need a token, I use setHeader(), but see an error saying auth token missing.

What am I missing ?

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(endPoint);

get.setHeader("Authorization", token);
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("exampleproxy.com",8080);
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom() .setProxy(proxy).build();
get.setConfig(config);

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);

BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Comment: Does your `token` variable contains the `Bearer` keyword?

Comment: Yes, it is "Bearer <token>"